# ipconfig/all doesn't give an ip address for ethernet port

Tags: windows, cmd, raspberry-pi, ip, ethernet

I have dynamic IP set up for my ethernet port on my laptop that's running windows 10. I want to connect a raspberry pi to my ethernet port (no internet involved), so naturally, I need the IP Address.I typed ipconfig/all into the cmd window on my laptop, but when the the listings come up there is no ipv4 address.
...how can I get the ip address to appear?

[screenshot of ipconfig/all](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hLIZH.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It’s been a while since I used windows but you probably can get your IP address back by renewing the DHCP lease. Go to a cmd prompt and type: ipconfig /renew. If that doesn’t work try a ipconfig /release then do another /renew.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer! I tried your suggestion and I got a message saying "No operation can be performed on Ethernet 2 while it has its media disconnected.
No operation can be performed on Local Area Connection* 2 while it has its media disconnected.
No operation can be performed on Bluetooth Network Connection while it has its media disconnected. "

Comment: You are connecting a rasberry pi ethernet port to the ethernet porton your laptop? You probably need a cross over cable or, use a hub/switch to connect the two. If you still have the problem after that post an outpout of your ifconfig /all.

Comment: Ok, I added a pic of the screenshot to the original post...and I am using a Cat5 ethernet cable so I believe that is a crossover cable

Comment: Looks like you don’t even have link on your ethernet port which also might suggest you need a crossover cable between the NIC’s to get link. If you have a ethernet switch just hook both of the interfaces into that and check for link. More info on crossover cables: https://www.lifewire.com/crossover-cable-ethernet-817870